# Why some internet providers close certain ports?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, port, network-protocols

We published the game on russian server and 1% of people couldn't connect to server on 46xx port through raw TCP while they can load it's HTML page (through HTTP). Most of such people live in Germany, Israel....
Why is it so? What's the politics decisions lay behind it? We discovered that their such ports (which are free on IANA) are closed. Does it mean that such people cannot run Steam (and, then, play all games which you can buy through it), play WoW and many other modern games which use TCP through 4xxx ports?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISPs have been known to filter certain ports for various reasons.  Users should *complain loudly* to them (or switch) in order to send a signal that such is not to be tolerated.  You can encourage them to do so but of course that doesn't solve your problem (or really answer your question).

Common reasons are:
- trying to block bittorrent traffic
- limit bandwidth usage (largely related to previous reason)
- security (mistaken)
- control (companies often don't want employees goofing off)

The easiest thing for you to do is run your game over port 443 (perhaps as an alternate).  That's HTTPS and so will not generally be blocked.  However, because HTTPS is encrypted, there's no way to inspect the stream to know if its web traffic or something else and thus you can run any data stream (encrypted or not) that you wish over it.

Answer (score 0):

That's precisely correct. In fact every public web site would by default block all ports except the ones they expect to be running some traffic they would want to.

This is the reason many applications often try to encapsulate their programs to use port 80 which can't be blocked as long as some one wants http traffic to run.

They simply don't want any application that they haven't approved to run through their servers. If you have a sensitive server in public you surely won't want any one to use your machine for any apps that you don't allow. A common reason is applications that eat up bandwidth such as bittorent, edonkey, gnutella as well as streaming, voip and other high bandwidth consuming apps

Comment: I still don't understand why providers block such ports? What is the reasong behind it?

Comment: They simply don't want any application that they haven't approved to run through their servers. If you have a sensitive server in public you surely won't want any one to use your machine for any apps that you don't allow. A common reason is applications that eat up bandwidth such as bittorent, edonkey, gnutella as well as streaming, voip and other high bandwidth consuming apps